# What to attribute the difference of observed probabilty in a bayesian model to simply sampling from data?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, prior

Comparing the probability from data that a zombie has iq > 18 **the bayesian approach**

```
# The IQ of a bunch of zombies
x <- c(19,23,20,17,23)

mean(x)
sd(x)

# Defining the parameter grid
pars <- expand.grid(mu = seq(0, 30, length.out = 100), 
                    sigma = seq(0.1, 20, length.out = 100))
# Defining and calculating the prior density for each parameter combination
pars$mu_prior <- dnorm(pars$mu, mean = 18, sd = 5)
pars$sigma_prior <- dunif(pars$sigma, min = 0, max = 10)
pars$prior <- pars$mu_prior * pars$sigma_prior
# Calculating the likelihood for each parameter combination
for(i in 1:nrow(pars)) {
  likelihoods <- dnorm(x, pars$mu[i], pars$sigma[i])
  pars$likelihood[i] <- prod(likelihoods)
}
# Calculate the probability of each parameter combination
pars$probability <- pars$prior * pars$likelihood 
pars$probability <- pars$probability/sum(pars$probability)

indicie <- sample(1:nrow(pars),rep = T,10000,prob = pars$probability)
```

After this, I generated iq from the posterior distribution of mean and sigma and got a probability of around **73%** of finding a zombie with iq higher than 18

**Simply Sampling from the data**

```
iq <- sample(x,100000,rep = T)
sum(iq>18)/100000
```

Here I got the probability of around **80%** of finding a zombie with iq higher than 18

Is the difference in probability I am seeing attributed to the prior of the model? Also, when should one go with the above approach rather than simply sampling from the data to generate inferences  ?